# How do I write a function that return True iff row exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some syntax problems probably.

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE    Customer(
        cid INTEGER primary key,
        age INTEGER NOT NULL
    );
```

This is my function try:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION valid_buy(cid INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS 
    RETURN SELECT exists(
                         select 1 
                         from Customer c 
                         where c.age>=18 and 
                         c.cid = cid
                        )
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax errors:

- you have to declare language of the function (SQL in this case),
- the function body must be enclosed in quotes, usually they are dollar-quotes,
- in an SQL function you cannot use `RETURN`.

You should also use arguments names other than a table columns to avoid ambiguity.

```
create or replace function valid_buy(_cid integer) 
returns boolean 
language sql as $$
select exists(
    select 1 
    from customer 
    where age >= 18 
    and cid = _cid
    )
$$;
```